# Can anyone explain this JavaScript grammar(syntax) please?

Tags: javascript, regex, grammar

I'm reading a js file at [here](https://res.mail.qq.com/zh_CN/htmledition/js/all2187l.js), on the very top of this js file you can find the following lines:

```
var 
gsAgent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
gsAppVer=navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase(),
gsAppName=navigator.appName.toLowerCase(),
gbIsOpera=gsAgent.indexOf("opera")>-1,
gbIsKHTML=gsAgent.indexOf("khtml")>-1
||gsAgent.indexOf("konqueror")>-1||gsAgent.indexOf("applewebkit")>-1,
gbIsSafari=gsAgent.indexOf("applewebkit")>-1,
gbIsIE=(gsAgent.indexOf("compatible")>-1&&!gbIsOpera)
||gsAgent.indexOf("msie")>-1,
gbIsTT=gbIsIE?(gsAppVer.indexOf("tencenttraveler")!=-1?1:0):0,
gbIsFF=gsAgent.indexOf("gecko")>-1&&!gbIsKHTML,
gbIsNS=!gbIsIE&&!gbIsOpera&&!gbIsKHTML&&(gsAgent.indexOf("mozilla")==0)
&&(gsAppName=="netscape"),
gbIsAgentErr=!(gbIsOpera||gbIsKHTML||gbIsSafari||gbIsIE||gbIsTT
||gbIsFF||gbIsNS),
gbIsWin=gsAgent.indexOf("windows")>-1||gsAgent.indexOf("win32")>-1,
gbIsVista=gbIsWin&&(gsAgent.indexOf("nt 6.0")>-1||gsAgent.indexOf("windows vista")>-1),
gbIsWin7=gbIsWin&&gsAgent.indexOf("nt 6.1")>-1,
gbIsMac=gsAgent.indexOf("macintosh")>-1||gsAgent.indexOf("mac os x")>-1,
gbIsLinux=gsAgent.indexOf("linux")>-1,
gbIsAir=gsAgent.indexOf("adobeair")>-1,
gnIEVer=/MSIE (\d+.\d+);/i.test(gsAgent)&&parseFloat(RegExp["$1"]),
gsFFVer=/firefox\/((\d|\.)+)/i.test(gsAgent)&&RegExp["$1"],
gsSafariVer=/version\/((\d|\.)+)/i.test(gsAgent)&&RegExp["$1"],
gsChromeVer=/chrome\/((\d|\.)+)/i.test(gsAgent)&&RegExp["$1"];
```

Now my question is what does it mean by ***RegExp["$1"]***, I can't find this syntax on the js documentation, but it's somewhat like ***Ruby***'s regex syntax. Can anyone explain it please? Great thanks.

PS:
Thanks S.Mark, now I know I can use it like this:

```
var a="abc23de";
alert(/(\d+)/.test(a)&&parseInt(RegExp["$1"]));
```

But where can I find the documentation of this syntax? Even the famous book ***JavaScript the definitive guide*** has not mentioned that RegExp can be used like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regexp.test() method populates the global RegExp object with what it has found, see [the full list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Deprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties)

```
/(\d+)(.+)/.test("123abc");
alert(RegExp["$1"]) // "123"
```

this way is deprecated, much better is to use exec() (and its string counterpart match())

```
var matches = /(\d+)(.+)/.exec("123abc");
alert(matches[1]) // "123"
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a browser user agent detection script and

`RegExp["$1"]` is Regular Expression Group 1, which would be

`(\d+.\d+)` in `/MSIE (\d+.\d+);/`

For example

- `6.0` in `MSIE 6.0`
- `20091126` in `Firefox/20091126`
- `0.2.153.1` in `Chrome/0.2.153.1`

**UPDATE**:

```
var a="abc23de";
alert(/(\d+)/.test(a)&&parseInt(RegExp["$1"]));
```

Above codes mean, if there is numbers in the string, extract those and parse it to Integer

Answer (score 2):

MDC site was down, so the best I can offer is [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dthzd08(VS.85).aspx) for the `RegExp` object.  In short `$1, $2, $3, ...$9` are properties of the `RegExp` object, containing the matches in order of appearance in the last executed regular expression.

Example (taken from MSDN):

```
function matchDemo(){
   var s;
   var re = new RegExp("d(b+)(d)","ig");
   var str = "cdbBdbsbdbdz";
   var arr = re.exec(str);
   s = "$1 contains: " + RegExp.$1 + "\n";
   s += "$2 contains: " + RegExp.$2 + "\n";
   s += "$3 contains: " + RegExp.$3;
   return(s);
}
```

The use of square braces in your example is just another way of accessing properties on an object - `RegExp.$1` is functionally the same as `RegExp["$1"]` (in this case).  This allows you to retrieve matching groups without using the `match` method.